# Bring rails object in javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to get in a js array, the values of the names of an user controller? If I have a controller that have name, username, password, birthday, etc., and I want to retrieve just the name in a javascript array like bellow:

`var user_names = ["firstuser","seconduser","thirduser"]`

How can I do that?

Another thing is that I want to use this to a search input, in the main page (/index). I think the controller is the application_controller, but for now, im testing in the user controller.

Bellow is the controller. Its not a 'user' its a student (aluno). The `alunos2` is just a test.

```
# encoding: utf-8
class AlunosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_aluno, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def autocomplete
    render json: Aluno.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:nome)
  end

  # GET /alunos
  # GET /alunos.json
  def index
    @alunos2 = Aluno.all
    @alunos = Aluno.search(params[:search]).order("LOWER(#{sort_column}) #{sort_direction}").paginate(:per_page => params[:npage], :page => params[:page])    
  end

  # GET /alunos/1
  # GET /alunos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /alunos/new
  def new
    @aluno = Aluno.new
  end

  # GET /alunos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /alunos
  # POST /alunos.json
  def create
    @aluno = Aluno.new(aluno_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @aluno.save
        format.html { redirect_to alunos_url, notice: 'Aluno foi criado com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @aluno }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @aluno.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /alunos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /alunos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @aluno.update(aluno_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @aluno, notice: 'Aluno foi atualizado com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @aluno }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @aluno.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /alunos/1
  # DELETE /alunos/1.json
  def destroy
    @aluno.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to alunos_url, notice: 'Aluno foi removido com sucesso.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_aluno
    @aluno = Aluno.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def aluno_params
    params.require(:aluno).permit(:nome, :sobrenome, :nascimento, :responsavel, :cpf, :rg, :telefone, :celular, :email, :rua, :numero, :bairro, :complemento, :cidade, :estado)
  end

  def sort_column
    Aluno.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "nome"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end

  # A list of the param names that can be used for filtering the Product list
  #private
  #def filtering_params(params)
    #params.slice(:status, :location, :starts_with)
  #end
end
```

Comment: So you have a ruby array in controller and you want to pass it to JS?

Comment: i dont have the array itself. But I have the object. Like customer or user. And in this object i have 'name', 'username', 'password', 'street', 'phone_number', etc. I want to pass an array of only the name attribute to javascript. :/

Comment: Could you post your controller code?

Comment: my controller is with a lot of content. but if you want i can post it anywhere.

Comment: @rodrigokiller : I wanted to see the objects you are talking about.

Comment: @Nitish ok, i added in the question.

Comment: @apneadiving Hey, i will take a look in that gem too, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the code bellow

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var alunos_list = <%= @alunos2.to_json.html_safe %>;
  var alunos_names = [];
  jQuery.each(alunos_list, function(i, val) {
    alunos_names.push(alunos_list[i].nome + ' ' + alunos_list[i].sobrenome);    
  });
<% end %>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can do the processing in rails. `var alunos_name = <%= @alunos2.map{|a| a.nome + ' ' + a.sobrenome }.to_json.html_safe %>;`